# How to send value recently selected in the url as a param?

Tags: jquery, struts2

I'm working on a struts2 (2.2.3) web app, using jquery plugin (3.0.0) for ajax.

I have a jsp in which I have 2 sj:autocompleter (the first one for providers and the second one for products). I need to filter the products by the provider selected. In this particular application is a must to have an autocompleter for the second collection.

What I want is to send in the url the value selected in the first autocompleter as a parameter so that I'm able to use that selection for filtering the second autocompleter.

Part of my jsp code:

```
<s:url id="url_products" action="myAction" method="showProducts">
    <s:param name="providerSelected" value="%{purchase.provider.id}"></s:param>
</s:url>

<sj:autocompleter 
id="purchaseProviderId" 
name="purchaseProvider" 
value="%{purchaseProvider}" 
onCompleteTopics="providerChanged"
cssClass="product" 
href="%{url_providers}" 
/>

<sj:autocompleter 
id="productId" 
name="productDescription" 
value="%{productDescription}" 
listenTopics="providerChanged"
href="%{url_products}" 
/>
```

The problem I'm having is that "%{purchase.provider.id}" is something selected exactly before sending the url_products and when I send the value through the url the value is not updated from the latest selection done. 
What I think is that this value is part of the session and since the new selection done for the provider has not been submitted yet to the action, "%{purchase.provider.id}" is just pointing to the value the session is aware of.

Question: How can I send the value recently selected in "purchaseProviderId" autocompleter through the url as a param?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See example for using double select at [Struts2-jQuery documentation](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag#A_simple_Doubleselect_with_Topics).

Notice that the second select has `formIds="formSelectReload"`.  This tells the action/url which is called to fill the second select that it depends on values in the `formSelectReload`.

In your case, you might have something like:

```
<s:form id='myForm'>
<sj:autocompleter 
id="purchaseProviderId" 
name="purchaseProvider" 
value="%{purchaseProvider}" 
onCompleteTopics="providerChanged"
cssClass="product" 
href="%{url_providers}" 
/>

<sj:autocompleter 
id="productId" 
name="productDescription" 
formIds="myForm"   <!-- This will send form values to action including selected purchaseProviderId -->
value="%{productDescription}" 
listenTopics="providerChanged"
href="%{url_products}" 
/>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. You were right, I added formIds to the second autocompleter and the "purchase.provider.id" is sent to the action. The only thing is that the id of the provider is not the recently selected, instead it's the id of the provider already selected/saved for this purchase and I need the new selected id.

Please note that I really need to use autocompleter component for this case. Any other suggestion for sending to the action the new provider id selected? Could I get that id from javascript and send it as a param in the url?

Comment: Add `onChangeTopics="providerChanged"` in your first select list.

Answer (score 0):

Add below mention code in you jsp page.

```
<sj:autocompleter 
    id="purchaseProviderId" name="purchaseProvider" 
    onSelectTopics="providerChanged"
    list="productMap"
    //Fill this map with the key value pair, and also make the getter 
    //and setter in order to have the access of the variable in jsp page
    cssClass="product"/>

<s:url id="provider" action="getProvider"/>
<sj:autocompleter 
    id="productId" name="productDescription" 
    listenTopics="providerChanged"
    listKey="key" listValue="value"
    href="%{provider}" />

<script type="text/javascript">     
var key;
$.subscribe('providerChanged', function(event, data) 
{
  var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
  key    = ui.item.key;

  //clear the children autocompleters
  jQuery('#productId').val("");
  jQuery('#productId_widget').val("");

  var options_branchCity_widget             = {};
  options_productId_widget.hiddenid         = "productId";
  options_productId_widget.delay            = 50;
  options_productId_widget.minimum          = 3;
  options_productId_widget.selectBox        = false;
  options_productId_widget.forceValidOption = true;
  options_productId_widget.jqueryaction     = "autocompleter";
  options_productId_widget.id               = "productId_widget";
  options_productId_widget.name             = "productDescription_widget";
  options_productId_widget.href             = "getProvider.action"+"?providerSelected="+key;
  options_productId_widget.listentopics     = "providerChanged";

  jQuery.struts2_jquery_ui.bind(jQuery('#productId_widget'),options_productId_widget); 
});
</script>
```

Add the below code in struts.xml file to register the respected action that will fetch the data for autocompleter.

```
<action name="getProvider" class="com.sample" method="getProvider">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="root">providerList</param>
    </result> 
</action>
```

Create the DTO class as mention below.

```
public class autocompleteDTO 
{
private String key;
private String value;

public autocompleteDTO(String key, String value) 
{
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
}

public String getKey() 
{
    return key;
}
public void setKey(String key) 
{
    this.key = key;
}

public String getValue() 
{
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) 
{
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

Add the below mention code in you action class to work the autocompleter.

```
public String getProvider()
{
   String userTypeCharacter = request.getParameter("term");
   String providerSelected  = request.getParameter("providerSelected");

   List providerListDB = //fetch list from the database with respect to user typed character
   //and providerSelected.       

   //Create the array list of the DTO class
   providerList= new ArrayList<autocompleteDTO>();

  //providerList will be the member variable of the action along with the getter and setter,
  //for data display in the jsp page

   //Iterate the list and add the data to another list
   for (Object provider: providerListDB ) 
   {
       Provider providerData = (Provider) provider;

       String providerCode = providerData .getProviderCode();
       String providerName = providerData .getProviderName();

       providerList.add(new autocompleteDTO(providerCode , providerName ));
   }
 }
 return SUCCESS;
}
```

This code will work on struts 2 and struts 2 jquery plugin 3.6.1.

If you any help then please let me know.
-Regards